# Make email public with url

Tags: email, sendgrid, mailgun, mailjet

It might not be an email integration problem but I would like to get solutions on it using various software available on internet or programming it using API.

Task:
I send money transaction confirmation emails using php/.net code to people and cc it to myself too. It is required to show the email to someone who does not have access to the email account.

Is it possible to automate any of the following:

1. Any way of showing an email sent from code/gmail/mailchimp/mandril/zapier/sendgrid as url
2. Any service already available that takes a screenshot of email from gmail/mailchimp/mandril/zapier/sendgrid etc. and post on a public url using ftp details
3. Programmatically take a screenshot of email sent from code/gmail/mailchimp/mandril/zapier/sendgrid and post on a public url using ftp details
4. Any other way of making email public of any email sent using code/gmail/mailchimp/mandril/zapier/sendgrid

Comment: Well, that's an interesting question.

Could you elaborate on the informations that may be asked by the bank ?

Are you looking for the e-mail Message-Id or Date fields ?

Comment: I was expecting that google must have this facility to provide a url to show an email to someone. already you can have a unique url for each email but that is visible to the owner of email address and not everyone and as far as I know there is no way to making the url public. However, google labs can give such future in future or it can be suggested to them.